# The tag wiki/excerpt for [mouse-guard] should probably be updated

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The tabletop RPG system [*Mouse Guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_Guard_Roleplaying_Game) (based on the comics of the same name) appears to have 2 editions. The first edition of the game was published in 2008, and the second edition was released in 2015.

Correspondingly, there are 2 tags for the [*Mouse Guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_Guard_Roleplaying_Game) RPG right now:

- The [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag was originally created in 2010. Its tag
  excerpt currently reads:

  > For questions about Mouse Guard, a tabletop RPG created by Luke Crane
  > based on the Mouse Guard comic books (by David Petersen) and his own
  > Burning Wheel system. The game was released by Archaia Studios Press
  > in 2008. It is set in a pseudo-medieval setting about an order of
  > anthropomorphic mouse rangers.
- The [mouse-guard-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard-2e) tag was created in 2017. Its tag wiki
  currently reads:

  > For questions about the second edition of the Mouse Guard tabletop
  > role-playing game. (See also: the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag.)

Neither of these tag wikis/excerpts have been edited in years. The original versions of those tag wikis/excerpts were very barebones, and it seems I've been the only one to revise the guidance for either tag since then – and all I did was copyedit and slightly expand on what was already there. Importantly, the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag guidance hasn't been meaningfully updated since before the 2nd edition even existed.

I know that our tagging practices have sometimes varied for other RPG system/edition tags, in terms of whether there is a "blanket" tag that covers multiple editions of a game (and if there is such a tag, whether that tag should be included in addition to a tag for the specific edition of the game that a question is about).

I'm not an expert on the *Mouse Guard* RPG system, so I can't really judge how the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag is being used right now. It seems like there are just [4 questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard+mouse-guard-2e) with both the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) and [mouse-guard-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard-2e) tags; there are another [30 questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard+-mouse-guard-2e) that have the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag but not the [mouse-guard-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard-2e) tag. (According to [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/188352/33569), the editions are not that different, so some of the questions in the latter category may be applicable to the system as a whole, and not system-specific.)

As such, it's not clear to me which approach is being taken with this tag.

As such, I think **the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag guidance should be updated to reflect the intended usage** (and depending on what that usage is, some retagging might be warranted as well):

- Should the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag only be used for questions about the
  1st edition? (If so, should it be renamed to [mouse-guard-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard-1e)?)
- Should the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag cover questions about the *Mouse
  Guard* RPG system as a whole or about multiple editions, but **not**
  questions about a single edition?
- Should the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag be included on **all** questions
  about *Mouse Guard* (whether they're about the system as a whole or
  about a particular edition), in addition to any edition-specific
  tags?
- Something else?

(I don't really favor any particular option here over the others; I just wanted to bring it to the community's attention so that the usage/guidance for the tag could be clarified accordingly.)

Whatever the community decides, the [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag guidance should probably be updated to reflect that consensus.

Comment: (Sorry if the structure of my post is hard to understand; it's late, and my thoughts are a bit jumbled.)

Comment: Peering at the [top users in mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/mouse-guard/topusers), I know Glazius is quite regularly active, I’d really like to hear their perspective here (no pressure though).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### I'm in favor of three tags total.

**Some questions under the existing [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag should be migrated to the new tag [mouse-guard-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard-1e).** A few questions under the existing tag ask about very specific things like conflict procedures with split mouse parties that only existed in the first edition of Mouse Guard, and have been removed in second edition.

**Keep the generic [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) tag.** A large number of questions about the system, however, don't have to be specific to 1E or 2E; 1E and 2E would give the same answer and an answer provided by somebody with only 1E knowledge would be largely useful in 2E still.

#### Update as of April 23

I've created a [mouse-guard-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard-1e) tag and attached it to the handful of 1e-specific questions we have.

Comment: I don't think all [tag:mouse-guard] questions should be migrated over, only a very small number *need* the [tag:mouse-guard-1e] tag.